# With html tables, using CSS, how do I get the tables next to each other?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am creating a pull from a database when searching it... I don't know how many results there will be, so I want to have them listed in a table, like this:

[user info, about 4 to 8 lines long] [user info, about 4 to 8 lines long] [user info, about 4 to 8 lines long]

and have it naturally push rows down the page as they cannot keep going wider, so if it can fit 2 or 3 together, based upon the width of the browser, then it can, but when no more fit, then start a new line...

I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have the table like this:

```
<table align="left" width="150" style="width: 150px; border-style: solid; border-color: {bordercolor}; border-width: 2px 2px 4px 2px;">
<tr>
    <td align="left" style="padding-left: 1cm;">
Member Id: {mbrid} <br />
<br />
Username: {un} <br />
Name: {name} <br />
email: {email} <br />
Status: {status} <br />
Referrer: {referrer} <br />
Options: <br />
{options} <br />
 <br />
    </td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Then all the data in {} are replaced by php.

but those are going down the page, and none next to each other.

So can you tell me what I did wrong?

Oh, by the way, this is just an admin function, so I did not care about the design being amazing... I guess maybe I should in case we ever sell the business? hmm. Food for thought.

Comment: Try adding display: inline-block or float:left in css. You could also look at flex box.

Comment: ah ok. forgot about float:left.... been so long since I've done a lot with css.

Comment: I tried just adding the float, to the main table cell, but that did not work. Anyhow, then I tried the ones below, and those both worked. Thank you for the reminder of those. I appreciate your response and how fast it was. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either use the table as a table with columns for Member ID, User Name etc, or as you a representin a list of users, I'd use a list

```css
.memberInfo
{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:none;
}

.memberInfo li
{
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  width:150px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

.memberInfo .label
{
  font-weight:bold;
}

.memberInfo .options
{
  display:block;  
}
```

```html
<ul class="memberInfo">
  <li>
    <div><span class="label">Member Id:</span> {mbrid}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Username:</span> {un}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Name:</span> {name}</div>
    <div><span class="label">email:</span> {email}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Status:</span> {status}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Referrer: </span> {referrer}</div>
    <div><span class="label options">Options:</span>
      {options}</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div><span class="label">Member Id:</span> {mbrid}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Username:</span> {un}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Name:</span> {name}</div>
    <div><span class="label">email:</span> {email}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Status:</span> {status}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Referrer: </span> {referrer}</div>
    <div><span class="label options">Options:</span>
      {options}</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><span class="label">Member Id:</span> {mbrid}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Username:</span> {un}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Name:</span> {name}</div>
    <div><span class="label">email:</span> {email}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Status:</span> {status}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Referrer: </span> {referrer}</div>
    <div><span class="label options">Options:</span>
      {options}</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><span class="label">Member Id:</span> {mbrid}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Username:</span> {un}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Name:</span> {name}</div>
    <div><span class="label">email:</span> {email}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Status:</span> {status}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Referrer: </span> {referrer}</div>
    <div><span class="label options">Options:</span>
      {options}</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><span class="label">Member Id:</span> {mbrid}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Username:</span> {un}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Name:</span> {name}</div>
    <div><span class="label">email:</span> {email}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Status:</span> {status}</div>
    <div><span class="label">Referrer: </span> {referrer}</div>
    <div><span class="label options">Options:</span>
      {options}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using a list will get you better flow on different screen sizes and more flexibilty for media query etc. You can then change the CSS to flex box easily if required.

I've replace `<br />` with `<div>` as it is more semantic and gives greater styling options.

Comment: I loved this one. It worked. Thank you so much. I rated it up and chose it as the answer. Thank you so much for your effort, I really appreciate it.

I added another line to the bottom: <div><hr width="100%"></div> so that I could easily see the bottom of each list. that worked good. thank you again!!

Comment: Better than `<hr>`  use border on the <li>....I've adjusted my snippet accordingly.

Comment: Good solution. A possible enhancement might be to replace the `<divs>` and `<spans>` in each `<li>` with a definition list: `<dl><dt>Member ID:</dt><dd>{mbrid}</dd><dt>Username:</dt><dd>{un}</dd><dt>Name:</dt><dd>{name}</dd> [...] </dl>`.

Comment: @Rounin I agree and was tempted to go that way but I decided to go with a simpler, but perhaps less optimal, solution.

Answer (score 1):

In an HTML table, the data-cells (nested inside the rows) line up horizontally, and the rows (containing the data cells) then stack vertically.

So... is this the kind of thing you are looking to achieve:

```css
table {
border: 2px solid black;
border-bottom-width: 4px;
}

td {
width: 150px;
padding-left: 1cm;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Member Id: {mbrid} <br />
Username: {un} <br />
Name: {name} <br />
email: {email} <br />
Status: {status} <br />
Referrer: {referrer} <br />
Options: <br />
{options} <br />
</td>
  
<td>
Member Id: {mbrid} <br />
Username: {un} <br />
Name: {name} <br />
email: {email} <br />
Status: {status} <br />
Referrer: {referrer} <br />
Options: <br />
{options} <br />
</td>
  
<td>
Member Id: {mbrid} <br />
Username: {un} <br />
Name: {name} <br />
email: {email} <br />
Status: {status} <br />
Referrer: {referrer} <br />
Options: <br />
{options} <br />
</td>
  
<td>
Member Id: {mbrid} <br />
Username: {un} <br />
Name: {name} <br />
email: {email} <br />
Status: {status} <br />
Referrer: {referrer} <br />
Options: <br />
{options} <br />
</td>
</tr>
  
<tr>
<td>
Member Id: {mbrid} <br />
Username: {un} <br />
Name: {name} <br />
email: {email} <br />
Status: {status} <br />
Referrer: {referrer} <br />
Options: <br />
{options} <br />
</td>
  
<td>
Member Id: {mbrid} <br />
Username: {un} <br />
Name: {name} <br />
email: {email} <br />
Status: {status} <br />
Referrer: {referrer} <br />
Options: <br />
{options} <br />
</td>
  
<td>
Member Id: {mbrid} <br />
Username: {un} <br />
Name: {name} <br />
email: {email} <br />
Status: {status} <br />
Referrer: {referrer} <br />
Options: <br />
{options} <br />
</td>
  
<td>
Member Id: {mbrid} <br />
Username: {un} <br />
Name: {name} <br />
email: {email} <br />
Status: {status} <br />
Referrer: {referrer} <br />
Options: <br />
{options} <br />
</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: This did work. Thank you. I liked the list better though, it turned out much smaller and easier to read. :) thank you so much for your effort though. I rated it up. :) thank you!!!! :) I appreciate you.